# Set X rows in UICollectionview

Tags: swift, view, uicollectionview, constraints

I have an UICollectionView inside of an UIViewcontroller. I want to know how to set a maximum of cells in each row.

This question was asked before here: [UICollectionView display 3 items per row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34116251/uicollectionview-display-3-items-per-row)

This is answered however in an Objective C. Therefore I can not understand the answer. Also, this is done programmatically. Is there a way to do this in the interface builder? Edit: 3 people reported this as a duplicate. Yes, of course it's a duplicated question, I literately already mentioned that. Again: the questions are given in Objective C which I can not read. Therefore the answer of this topic should differ from the the topic I already mentioned.

So this is the case. I want to know if its possible to display 3 items in a row. So if there are 4 items, the first row displays 3 cells and the second row displays the other cell. I tried it with autolayout, but this is not how it works I guess. The cell's size remains the same. This way the cell's size is the same on all devices. This is not what I want. The width and height of the cell should be proportional to the view's width and heights. Let say view.width * 0.25 and height view.height * 0.5.

Edit: I already tried this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {      
   return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width/4 - 0, height: collectionView.bounds.size.height/4 - 0)
}
```

And played with the number's (4 and 0) but not the result I wanted.

Edit: **Found it out**
Final answer: if you want to have 3 rows, and make sure minimal spacing is higher than 0:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
   return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width/4 - 0, height: collectionView.bounds.size.height/1.5)
}
```

Comment: FYI - The question you linked is not in an older version of Swift. It's in Objective-C.

Comment: Oops :( gonna edit it

Comment: maybe this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/40826741/6448167
OR http://stackoverflow.com/a/14675248/6448167

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UICollectionView display 3 items per row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34116251/uicollectionview-display-3-items-per-row)

Comment: Yes KSigWyatt, I already mentioned it in my question. The answers are given in an other language. How could that possibly help me if I can not understand it? And thank you for redirecting me to the topics. However again is one answer in Objective C and the other answer did not help me. I updated the question and included a function that didn't work.

Comment: Edit: It worked after I changed some code xCode suggested.

Comment: If it works, post answer for others to read.